# Python not creating simple txt file by using "write"

Tags: python

I wrote this simple code and no text file was created. I also tried to create it manually in the same folder and append something on and that also didn't work.

```
employee_file = open("employees.txt" , "w")

employee_file.write("toby human resources")

employee_file.close()
```

Comment: Please do not include images in your question, but rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: your code works, have you checked permission errors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Please include the entire error message.

Comment: Thanks for info,didnt know about that.

Comment: @E.Serra there were no errors code was ran succsessfully but no folder was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really put the code in the question. After some time the image will probably be deleted and many people won't be able to benefit from your question.

Try the following code:

```
import os
print (os.getcwd())

employee_file = open("employees.txt" , "w")

employee_file.write("toby human resources")

employee_file.close()
```

It should print the current working directory, where the file should be saved.

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - your code is correct.
Secondly - why not use "built-in" statements (which closes the file so we don't have take care of it)

```
with open('employees.txt','w') as file:
   file.write("some data")
   # do sth else ...
```

and we don't have to close the file here.